# Why does my macro skip the second For loop?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have an issue where my macro skips my second For loop. What's the reason for this? My macro enters a few fields, then in the loop it finds the value of a field from the 'Master' worksheet, then copies the fields to the right. There are two lists of items i want it to look for. The first is from A6-A13, and the second list is from A17-A21. However it skips the second loop altogether.

I've used F8 and watched it go through step by step, It moves through the first part of the macro OK, then moves through the first loop the correct number of times, however when it finished, It gets to the next For loop (highlights it as the next step to execute) , then completely skips it and goes to the range formatting after that? Why doesn't it execute the second loop at all?

```
 ExportNumRows = Range("A17", Range("A17").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
 Range("A3").Value = ImportNumRows
 Range("A15").Value = ExportNumRows
 
 Dim counter As Integer
 
 
'Start of loop
 For counter = 6 To ImportNumRows + 5
 Set rng = Worksheets("Averages").Cells(counter, 1)
 Set rng2 = Worksheets("Master").Columns("A:A").Find(What:=rng.Value, MatchCase:=True)
   If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
    rownumber = rng2.Row
    rng.Offset(0, 1) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(rownumber, 2).Value
    rng.Offset(0, 2) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(rownumber + 1, 3).Value
    rng.Offset(0, 3) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(rownumber + 2, 3).Value
    Else
    End If
    
'End of loop
Next counter


'Start of loop
For counter = 17 To ExportNumRows + 5
 Set rng = Worksheets("Averages").Cells(counter, 1)
 Set rng2 = Worksheets("Master").Columns("A:A").Find(What:=rng.Value, MatchCase:=True)
   If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
    rownumber = rng2.Row
    rng.Offset(0, 1) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(rownumber, 2).Value
    rng.Offset(0, 2) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(rownumber + 1, 3).Value
    rng.Offset(0, 3) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(rownumber + 2, 3).Value
    Else
    End If
    
'End of loop
Next counter

'Formats various columns, changes average column to 2 decimal places
Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "0.00"
Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "0.00"
Columns("B:D").AutoFit
```

Comment: What is the value of `ExportNumRows` when you put a breakpoint on that line? Is it 11 or less?

Comment: Don't you need for counter=17 to 17+exportnumrows

Comment: Just curious, You say : _The first is from A6-A13, and the second list is from A17-A21_.  Is it a fixed range ? or is it because the current value of A3 is 8 (the ImportNumRows) and the current value of A15 is 16 (the ExportNumRows) that's why you say like that ?

Comment: `Range("A17", Range("A17").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count` returns the number of rows AFTER `A17` - You are not getting the absolute Row, but the amount of rows that are below A17, the relative last row so to speak (For example if your Values go down to Row 19 it will return 2) - Also: If there are no rows with values after `A17` you'll get 1048560 - Which is probably bad (and should be avoided by checking againts it)

Comment: Hi all, to start, Im fairly new to vba so there will be better ways of doing these things Im sure.

Comment: @braX There was a line I inserted so I know what the value is. The current value is 5. What would a breakpoint do?

Comment: @Black cat - Im not sure? Do I?

Comment: @Karma Its relatively fixed. Its a list of staff members - so might fluctuate a little, but not every day. What I hope to achieve is the loops looks at A6, then finds the value from column A of the Master worksheet, then copy the cell "2 columns to the right and one down" and enter that into C6 of the Averages sheet.
This works for the first list, but not the second.

Comment: @Lord-Julian Yes this is to get the count of how many rows to use in the loop (As far as Im aware?). So loop 2 would start at A17 and run for the value of ExportNumRows (5) loops.
Maybe my issue is that it's not starting the second loop at A17?

Comment: @PaulOmeara if you get the number of times the loop should run, why are you starting the loop at 17 and not at 1? If you loop from `17 To 18` The loop will have to iterations (i = 17 and i = 18) - The loop will not run 18 times. It will run from the start value to the end value. Meaning you either have to change your start value, or your end value in order to have a loop that iterates the wanted amount of times

Comment: @Blackcat - I tested this and this works! Thanks for that.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII Thanks for that. Yes you're right. I thought it was starting at the right point. But obviously not. I thought 'counter=17' means its starting at row 17. So i thought it would from 17 to.... "the amount of rows" BUT as Blackcat pointed out it should be Start at 17 ending at "17 + Row count"